# Orderdoctrine collection by presence of records on related table

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have Table QuoteOrder (id, user_id, foo, bar)

I also have table QuoteOrderRecurrence (id, quote_order_id, date, etc)

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->from('QuoteOrder qo')
->leftJoin('q.sfGuardUser sfg')
->where('qr.user_id = ?', $userId);
```

Is it possible to order this query by the date on QuoteOrderRecurrence.
Not all QuoteOrders have QuoteOrderRecurrence records so I want to list out those that have QuoteOrderRecurrence records first(ordered by date) followed by those without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->from('QuoteOrder qo')
->leftJoin('qo.sfGuardUser sfg')
->leftJoin('qo.QuoteOrderRecurrence qor')
->where('qr.user_id = ?', $userId)
->orderBy('qor.date DESC');
```

Check the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79bde/6/0).